# meteor: facebook signin status

Tags: facebook, meteor

How do I check and get the username from the facebook login?? I successful get the account-facebook to work but I don't know how to access to the username?

Meteor is cool but not much documentation. Or I am to new for must of the server side javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an object (services) where facebook info is stored on  [Meteor users](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users). You can get accessToken, id, username, etc.

You can use [onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser) to modify the user document and add the username on creation.

```
# on server
# coffeescript
Accounts.onCreateUser (options, user) ->
  if user.services.facebook
    data = user.services.facebook
    user.username = data.username or "generateOne"
    return user
```

You can use `user.profile` to add other fields.